# What is the unit of sound when measuring by an Android smartphone?

Tags: android

Here is my code

```
    private static int Fs = 44100; 
    private byte recorderAudiobuffer[] = new byte [1024];
    AudioRecord recorder = new  AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, Fs, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 4096);
    //start recorder
    recorder.startRecording();
```

A value is identified by bin[n] and bin[n+1] of recorderAudiobuffer[].

What unit are these values?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the `recordAudiobuffer[]` elements would be 1/44100 second, since your sample rate is 44100 Hz.

As for the value of the bytes they hold, it could mean any sound level.  If the sensitivity is low, the maximum value for the bytes could be, I don't know, 12, even if the sound you're recording is loud.  On the other hand, with the sensitivity turned up, 255 could be a whisper, and it's railed after that.

Comment: sorry, but im not understand
i need to know unit of which is measured above (db, V, ....)
thanks for answer

Comment: If you're recording on the device, it's going to be a scaled value for the voltage measured on the microphone.  Zero is the minimum, 255 is the maximum.  What amplitude (dB) the sound actually is depends on a lot of other things like gain, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is more an audio question :), but here it goes, to be simple as much as possible, sound data has two dimensions, one is time based and other is sample based, so you have a sound separated on 44100 * (sample rate for example 16bits per amplitude) you have 705600 bits needed for one second or 88200, and in this case if you have a same sampling you will have 11.6 something milliseconds of buffer.

And of course you are asking about amplitude values.

Hope this helps and enjoy your work.